# Fell for Delta Airlines scam (they charged my credit card before contacting me!) What now?

Tags: scams

Last night I received a phone call from "Delta Airlines Purchase Verification Department" claiming that I had purchased a flight. Since I was not travelling on the flight, they wanted to verify that it was authorized. Before I called them I did verify that they had actually charged my credit card with "DELTA AIR LINES, INC".

Since I could not find a phone number on Delta's website I called the phone number left on my voicemail for their "Purchase Verification Department" and apparently initiated a refund on the flight. I also cancelled my credit card and alerted the CC company to the fraud to initiate a refund.

This morning I was concerned and wanted to double check that everything was cancelled and just called the general Delta Airline phone number from their website. They said that the number I called last night was not one of theirs and that they have no record of the flight.

Evidently I called back a scam number. What now? When I called them I did not provide any information other than my first name and the "reference number" they gave me. It seems though that I would have confirmed my full name, phone number and address for them as they would have needed all of those to successfully put a charge on my (now cancelled) credit card and to phone me.

**What should I be on the look out for in the future? Other credit card stealing? Would this be enough that I should be worried about my credit and put a watch on it? Could they try to access other accounts of mine somehow?**

Oddly, even after calling them last night to "cancel the flight" I got a text this morning about "my flight details". I can't think of any reason why they would persist in the scam after receiving confirmation that I knew my credit card was compromised. I suppose it is not overly important but why on earth would they be continuing at this point, and with real flight data?

Answer (score 2):

In any case, you must contact your credit card company(VISA, Master,Amex, etc) or bank, not the merchant. Because scammer maybe taking the opportunity to confirm the victim details in order to conduct subsequent scam.

This is a close call of [Phishing and communication](https://www.aa.com/i18n/customer-service/support/communication-and-email-security.jsp) scam.

When you contact the credit card issuing company, they will cancel your existing card and issue a new one to you.

Comment: I did that last night. Just wondering if there is any additional actions I should take to protect myself now that I confirmed my personal details for a scammer :(

Comment: @BunnyKnitter  Perhaps also changing all your online account password.